# Como conseguir um Observable de um item de array?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Trabalhando com `Observable` e RxJS, me deparei com o seguinte problema. Em determinado ponto do código, meu acesso ao banco é feito da seguinte forma:

```
getExemplo(id: number):Observable<Exemplo>{
  return this.http.get<Exemplo[]>(PATH)
  // TODO filtrar array dentro do observable para pegar item correto
}
```

Como eu posso realizar uma filtragem dentro desse `Observable` de forma a retornar apenas o primeiro item cujo o `id` seja igual ao `id` passado como parâmetro?

Comment: Não é melhor na parte de acesso ao banco já fazer esse filtro? (eu não sei se você tem essa possibilidade, isso seria bom colocar, você tem dominio ou é de terceiros?)

Comment: Tá mais pra uma experiência que tô fazendo, pra aprender como usar filtros em um Observable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A ideia é usar as operações `pipe` e `map`, para mapear a resposta para o que você precisa:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

getExemplo(id: number): Observable<Exemplo>{
  return this.http.get<Exemplo[]>(PATH).pipe(
    map(exemplos => exemplos.filter(e => e.id === id)[0])
  );
}
```

No caso, `exemplos` é o array de `Exemplo`, do qual você filtra os elementos pelo ID.

Só um detalhe: o [método `filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) retorna **outro array**, contendo os elementos filtrados. Então para pegar o primeiro elemento você deve usar `[0]` logo depois, para que o retorno seja `Observable<Exemplo>` (que é o que `getExemplo` está retornando).

Se você só usar `filter` (sem pegar o primeiro elemento com `[0]`), o retorno será um array, e o resultado será um `Observable<Exemplo[]>`.

---

Obviamente o código acima assume que sempre existirá um elemento com o ID indicado. Mas se quiser, também pode verificar se `filter` retornou um array vazio. E caso seja vazio (ou seja, nenhum elemento com o ID foi encontrado) retorne `null`, por exemplo (ou tome qualquer outra ação que julgar necessária):

```
getExemplo(id: number): Observable<Exemplo>{
  return this.http.get<Exemplo[]>(PATH).pipe(
    map(exemplos =>  {
      let filtrados = exemplos.filter(e => e.id === id);
      if (filtrados.length > 0) { // tem pelo menos um elemento com o ID
        return filtrados[0]; // retorna o primeiro
      }
      // nenhum elemento com o ID foi encontrado, retorna null
      return null;
    })
  );
}
```

Usando o código acima, bastaria então verificar se o `Exemplo` retornado é `null`:

```
getExemplo(123).subscribe(exemplo => {
    if (exemplo) {
        // exemplo com ID 123 existe
    } else {
        // exemplo com ID 123 não existe
    }
}
```

---

Outra alternativa é usar o [método `find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
getExemplo(id: number): Observable<Exemplo>{
  return this.http.get<Exemplo[]>(PATH).pipe(
    map(exemplos => exemplos.find(e => e.id === id))
  );
}
```

O `find` retorna o primeiro elemento do array que satisfaz a condição, ou `undefined` se nenhum for encontrado.

Answer (score 5):

Voce tem que mapear a reposta so pro item que vc quer:

```
 return this.http.get<Exemplo[]>(PATH).pipe(
       map(response => { //map do rxjs
              return response.filter(item=>item.id===id); // filter do array nativo
      })
 )
```

Comment: Acho que deve trocar o tipo de retorno também, já que agora só retorna uma objeto, ficaria: ```return this.http.get<Exemplo>(PATH)``` e o restante do código que você colocou.

Comment: Acho que ta certo porque esse tipo é em relação ao get e não o que acontece depois do pipe

Comment: Ah sim. Faz sentido. Tem razão.